# jquery autocomplete source as a url that takes in query strings

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jQuery Autocomplete UI widget on a text box and I am having no luck getting the source to work.  I have a database full of names that I want the autocomplete to work against, so I created a page called searchpreload.aspx and it looks for a variable in the url and queries the db based on the querystring vraiable.

When I type in the search box, I am using the keyup function so I can capture what the value is that needs to be sent over.  Then I do my string gathering from the db:

```
 if (Request.QueryString["val"] != null)
        {
            curVal = Request.QueryString["val"].ToString();
            curVal = curVal.ToLower();
            if (Request.QueryString["Type"] != null)
                type = Request.QueryString["Type"].ToString();

            SwitchType(type,curVal);
        }
```

It queries the database correctly and then it takes the strings and puts them in a list and prints them out to the page:

```
private void PreLoadStrings(List<string> PreLoadValues, string curVal)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (PreLoadValues.Any())
        {
            foreach (string str in PreLoadValues)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
                    if (str.ToLower().Contains(curVal))
                        sb.Append(str).Append("\n");
                }
            }
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This works fine, if I navigate to this page I get a listing of all of the data that I need, however I can not get it to show up in the autocomplete box.  When I debug the code, the source of the autocomplete is calling this page correctly each time and getting the correct data, it just is not displaying anything.  Am I doing something wrong?

JQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $(".searchBox").focus();
              var checked = 'rbCNumber';
              $("input:radio").change(function (eventObject) {
                  checked = $(this).val();
              });
              $(".searchBox").keyup(function () {
                  var searchValue = $(".searchBox").val();
                  //alert("Searchpreload.aspx?val=" + searchValue + "&Type=" + checked);
                  $(".searchBox").autocomplete({
                      source:"Searchpreload.aspx?val=" + searchValue + "&Type=" + checked,
                      minLength: 2


                  });
              });

          });      
  </script>
```

Also, should I be doing this a different way to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent displaying the results into anything - source will return a data item that you can then use to populate something else on the page. Look at autocomplete's select and focus methods.

here is an example of how i have done it:

```
field.autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: "whatever",
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    field.val(ui.item.Id);
                    return false;
                },
                search: function (event, ui) {
                    addBtn.hide();
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    setup(ui);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.Id+ ", " + item.Name + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
            };
```

The .data part is the part you are missing. Once the data comes back from the autocomplete you arent doing anything with it.

The source does not need to include the term the user entered into the search box. Jquery will automatically append the term onto the query string for you. If you watch the request get generated in firebug, you will see the term query hanging off the end of the url.

Comment: I am confused with what you are saying.  If I take the basic autocomplete example (the one with the search values in an array) and just call $(".searchBox").autocomplete({
                      source: values}) it displays everything correctly in a dropdown even though there is no <li></li> items or anything.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ - default functionality.

all I want is my result set to show and filter each time a new keystroke is entered.

Comment: Oh, it seemed like it wasn't returning anything back out for you. In that case just don't bind the autocomplete to a keyup. Autocomplete should handle the keyup detection on its own and doesn't need you to put it in the keyup function. If you need it to do OTHER stuff on keyup, you can do that in a keyup function on that field.

Comment: This is not working as well.  I have removed the keyup function, however if I do that, how does the autocomplete know what value to send through to my url where the data is stored?  I am very confused as to how this works and why I am not getting any data sent back to my autocomplete.  Does the autocomplete ui functionality store the text (as it is typed) in a variable I can send through as a querystring for my source?

Comment: Correct, the search term is always passed along - by default I believe it comes as a "term=?" query string part. The "source" merely specifies the data source to query against. If you are calling a page method or something like that, it should send a query string of term and you just need to have your page method handle it.

Comment: ok so how can I send the term through as a variable to my source to my querystring?  This is one of the most confusing jQuery items I have come across but I am new so please excuse my ignorance...

Comment: the term comes on your query string automatically - jquery will append it to your query string for you. so, if your source looks like:

source: /page.aspx?something=" + someValue,

it will come to your page method as:

/page.aspx/something=whatever&term=searchval. You just need to have your page method or mvc action handle it.

Comment: Great, that is one step closer.  I can see the data going through from the search box into the page that stores the data and does the database interaction.  I am still not getting the db values to show up in the autocomplete under the search box.  The source page is displaying the correct data but I can not see it under the search box.  How does the web page that holds all of the returned data from the db send the list of values to the search box to show as the auto complete?

Comment: In my example I was calling an MVC action that returned a JSON object - I am not sure how to do it with page methods but I am pretty sure your page method needs to return something back out that you need to handle on the jquery end.